# Access an IBOutlet from another class

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, iboutlet

I have 2 swift files the one is my HomeViewController and the second is my EventCollectionViewCell. In the second one I have an IBOutlet = informationView :UIView and I want to access this from the HomeViewController.

Is there any way ? 
Thank you in advance,
KS

Comment: To access the IBOutLet, you have to access the object of that ViewController first. But this is really bad practice. If you want to make changes on your 1st VC from 2nd VC, you should use Delegate pattern instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I suppose that in HomeViewController you have a UICollectionView and that acts as a datasource for it, then in your collectionView dataSource you can make:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventCollectionViewCell

    //Here you can access the IBOulets define in your cell
    cell.informationView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    return cell
}
```

***Edit:***

Problem: When you tap on a cell you want to show an Overlay inside the cell.

Solution: 
You need you data model to maintain the state, if it's active or not (the informationView), suppose that `ItemCell` is my model (in your case Event can be):

```
class ItemCell{
    var active:Bool = false
}
```

In the `collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you're going to check the current status of your model, and base on that, show or hide that overlay:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventCollectionViewCell

    let event = self.data[indexPath.row]
    //Here you can access the IBOulets define in your cell
    cell.informationView.hidden = !event.active

    return cell
}
```

Then as a final step, every time you select a cell (`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` method), you're going to update the status of your model:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    let event = self.data[indexPath.row]
    event.active = !event.active
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Sample Project:
https://github.com/Abreu0101/SampleTap

Comment: Thank you so much José for your quick response.
Your code worked but I have a problem . I want to add a Tap gesture recogniser on my informationView and when I tap my app broken and I get this error : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[wallhab.HomeViewController Tapp]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1365c14d0'

Comment: The code I use is :
 ` let aSelector : Selector = "Tapp"
 let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector)
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture) `

And I add this code to my collectionView function as you told me:
  ` func Tapp(){
   print("tap tap")
   cell.informationView.hidden = false
} `

Comment: Could you help me please ?

Comment: Hi @kstefanou, I don't understand, that part of the tapGesture is another question? Specifically, What do you want to do?

Comment: Hello Jose and thank you for your time. I want to add a tap gesture. When I tap I want to show a view (informationView) but the information view is declared in my EventCollectionViewCell file. And when I add the code in the function that you told me I get the error I wrote below. I hope you understand and thank you in advance. Ks

Comment: @kstefanou Oh to be sure that I understand. You have a view (hidden in it's initial state) inside your EventCollectionViewCell, and you want that when the cell is tapped, that the view appear (like an overlay inside the cell)? Is it correct?

Comment: exactly! But when I run my app and tap the app freezes.

Comment: @kstefanou I update the answer with a sample project, In this case a use directly the delegate method of `UICollectionViewDelegate` (In other words, it's not necessarily to use a tap for what you want to do).

Comment: I'm so sorry for my late response but I was on a business travel abroad. I just checked the sample project you uploaded and it works exactly as I want. But I have a problem my data array is eventName = [String]() and eventImage = [PFFile]() and I fill these arrays with parse commands with data that are stored on my database. So what is my ItemCell in my project? I'm deeply thankful for your help and for your time. You really helped me understand your solution and thank your for creating a sample project just for me.

Answer (score 0):

Follow what Jose has answered and if you are creating the cell in the interface builder. Set the class of the cell in Identity Inspector to EventCollectionViewCell and set the cell identifier to "cellIdentifier" that Jose has specified.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a property for that cell and access IbOutlets through that object.

@property (nonatomic, strong) MSSearchHeaderView *searchHeaderView;

if (self.searchHeaderView.searchTextField.text.length <= 0) {

```
        self.searchHeaderView.clearButton.hidden = YES;
```

}else{

```
        self.searchHeaderView.clearButton.hidden = NO;
```

}